# How to make default tab bar as full transparent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

[Transperent image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6HQj.png)I am working on a tab bar application.I applied the color to the tab bar like this

```
 [[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:137.0/255.0f green:27.0/255.0f blue:2.0/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
```

My requirement is to display the tab bar transparent like below image

After applying the below code.tab bar is not displaying transparent. but it is displaying with black color background

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = YES;
```

Give suggestions for making the default tab bar as transperent
[black color background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOrQB.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty image and pass it as a `backgroundImage`:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
```

You can use a similar approach for shadows and tint, but pay attention that a tint color is something very particular that has to deal with you whole UI.

Comment: Thank you for giving suggestion. Its working now.I applied the code like this now it working .                                                                                                   [[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:137.0/255.0f green:27.0/255.0f blue:2.0/255.0f alpha:0.92f]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
   [[UITabBar appearance] setTranslucent:YES];
    UIImage*bgimage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_49.png"];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:bgimage];